# skips the first line of input argument

Tags: shell, awk, scripting

```
read                          #reads input 
awk 'BEGIN {FS=";"}           #file seperator=;
{
    c=0;
    if($2=="programmer"||$2=="Programmer"||$2="PROGRAMMER")   #checks if the person is a programmer
    {
        print $1","$2","$3","$3*12;
        c=c+1;
    }
}
END {
    if(c==0)
    {
        print "no programmer";
    }
}'
```

when I execute this script, it always skips reading the first line of the input argument and continues with the second one.

Comment: Provide sample input that demonstrates the problem. Also double-check your use of `==` and `=`.

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned any variable which will contain the value entered by user as part of read command, mention a variable and pass it to awk command, then it should fly.

```
read var                         #reads input

echo "$var" |
awk 'BEGIN {FS=";"}              #file separator=;
{
    c=0;
    if($2=="programmer"||$2=="Programmer"||$2=="PROGRAMMER")   #checks if the person is a programmer
    {
        print $1","$2","$3","$3*12;
        c=c+1;
    }
}
END {
    if(c==0)
    {
        print "no programmer";
    }
}'
```

Also(what Shawn has mentioned in his comments under question section), you need to change from `=` TO `==` to make it correct condition in your `$2=="PROGRAMMER"` section.

In case if user could enter more than these 3 types mentioned(value of programmer), you can actually do this, change your if condition to `if(tolower($2)=="programmer")` in above code.

Comment: I did what you said and my script just prints the first line of the input arguments.

Comment: @YashwanthY, the answer was given as per your shown problem, since its not clear what is your sample input and expected sample output I can't really say why its NOT running, basically I have taken your code only :)

Comment: input: yashwanth;programmer;50000 #newline vishal;tech_support;40000 #newline avinash;Programmer;70000   Ouput: yashwanth,programmer,50000,600000 #newline avinash,Programmer,840000

Answer (score 0):

The first group of statements is executed for each input line, which means that in **each** input line, the variable `c` will be reset to zero. By the time the `END` clause is calculated, `c` contains the value from the last line.

I would move the initialization `c=0` into the `BEGIN` clause.

Comment: sure thing mate